# Electron register to loaded URL window.postMessage

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a web application I host inside Electron using

```
new BrowserWindow({...}).loadURL(...)
```

The url hosted, somewhere along its life cycle triggers

```
window.postMessage(...)
```

I want to be able to register to 'message' events from the URL I load using window.loadURL.

```
// similar to
window.addEventListener('message', myHandler)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you control the source code of the website you're loading? If not, this somewhat feels like eavesdropping. Also, what would be your usecase for this?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I host my web application. And when the web application finishes a task, I want to notify electron. I didn't how to do it so instead I'm registering to page-title-change, and I set the title with JSON.stringify(...) and it works perfectly as if it is a post message.
Hackish, but working :)